# Laravel - show rich text

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want save and show rich text in Laravel.
There are many ways to do that ( for both purpose ). In our view we can use two expression :

1. `{!! $text !!}`
2. `{!! html_entity_decode($text) !!}`

I know that both of them are correct. but first one doesn't work sometimes ( for example when i want copy WordPress posts to Laravel ). What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the relevant documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

The first `$text` does not get decoded, the seconds does.

The difference would be for example:

```
&lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

Your first example would echo this exact string which is not useful.
e.g.

> <b>bold</b>

As the string literal. This would not render as bold.

The second example would decode this to

```
<b>bold</b>
```

Which would be rendered as

> **bold**

However this does need one very big warning as does every answer which requests the use of `{!! !!}`.
All the code between `{!! !!}` is in danger of executing random scripts placed by the user for example. please be aware of these security implications and the source of your `$text`.
More information on echoing data can be found [at the laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data).

Comment: but we can't use `{{ html_entity_decode($text) }}` !. is there any replacement ?

Comment: Your best option would be to sanitise all input. i.e. limit the available tags for users. There is a pretty reliable and objective post on input sanitisation from the HTML Purifier creator [here](http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison).

Comment: Can we use something like this `{!! html_entity_decode(clean($text)) !!}` ? `clean()` is a function for purifier. is there any security problem yet ?

Comment: Help with usage might be batter suited as a separate question. No security advice here can be guaranteed 100% correct or is legally binding.
No, this would not work, however, switching the 2 calls e.g. `clean(html_entity_decode($test))` would, since the inner function would generate the tags and `clean` could then properly filter those tags.

Answer (score 2):

Use `{{ }}` instead of `{!! !!}`. According to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade):

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>   `Hello, {!! $name !!}`

Comment: Thanks. but i want **effectiveness** of `html_entity_decode()`

Comment: @ArashHatami no problem. Can you elaborate on what you mean by effectiveness? Thanks.

Comment: These brackets (`{{ }}`) would encode the data instead of decoding it.